# Why does Visual Studio 2019 run tests in dotnet core 1.0 even though my projects target dotnet core 2.2?

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, vstest

I have a solution with 2 projects, one of which is a test project. Both projects target dotnet core 2.2:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
```

I am using Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.1.1). When I click "Run all" in test explorer, it outputs this warning in output window:

```
[5/28/2019 10:25:40 PM Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[5/28/2019 10:25:40 PM Warning] Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 and platform X64. Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform settings.
MyApp.UnitTests.dll is built for Framework 2.2 and Platform AnyCPU.
Go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=236877&clcid=0x409 for more details on managing these settings.

[5/28/2019 10:25:41 PM Informational] ========== Run test finished: 3 run (0:00:01.167997) ==========
```

The tests do run, and finish successfully. But I am wondering about how to get rid of this warning.

I added a .runsettings file with following settings, but I still see the same warning.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>FrameworkCore10</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

Changing FrameworkCore10 to FrameworkCore22 (or netcoreapp2.2) throws a huge exception. Top few lines of the exception:

```
[5/28/2019 10:41:30 PM Error] System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RequestConfiguration.GroupTestContainersConfigByFrameworkAndArchitecture(IEnumerable`1 testContainersConfig, IXPathNavigable runSetting)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestRunConfiguration.<GetAllCriteriaQueues>d__64.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestRunRequest.<CreateRequests>d__23.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<RunRequests>d__95.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Note that the same projects work fine in Visual Studio 2017, without the need of any runsettings file whatsoever.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with VS 2019 and xUnit targeting Core 2.2 and 3.0. That's probably a problem of the Visual Studio MSTest adapter. Have you tried to run the tests with [dotnet test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test?tabs=netcore21)? If you can, it means the problem is in the VS test adapter, or at least, it's not in the console test runner

Comment: Have you tried updating the NuGet packages of the test project? `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` and whatever testing framework you use are added as NuGet packages. Perhaps the problem is already solved in a newer version. Or you could do what the .NET Core team itself does and use xUnit

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos All the nuget packages in the project are on the latest stable update. Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk is on 16.1.0. MSTest.TestAdapter & MsTest.TestFramework are on 1.4.0. I will give dotnest test a try and report back. One thing to not is that this is an azure function app project, and a normal test project.

Comment: Facing exactly the same problem right now. All I could find online is to try to set the framework version in .runsettings to ".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2". But it seems like vs is ignoring those settings anyways...

Comment: Also seeing the same problem. Updated to latest VS2019, xunit v2.4.1 and Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk v16.1.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not an answer, but posting to help others landing here.

Visual Studio team has acknowledged the issue and is looking into fixing this. It's best to follow it here:

- Issue at VS Developer Community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/579073/test-discovery-reporting-dlls-do-not-match.html
- Related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/1305

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem after upgrading from a netframework project to netcore.

Using VS Enterprise 16.3.8, cleaning the solution as well as deleting all temporary folders such as `bin` and `obj` helped me to get the tests running in the desired netcore version.

**Edit:**
As a sidenote VS has sometimes problems, when changing the target framework. After changing it deleting the `bin` / `obj` could sometimes be your last escape.

Answer (score -1):

It might be 2.2 dot net framework doesn't install in that machine.

Here is [Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=1639), you can download the framework.

Comment: 1.0 isn't even supported any more

Comment: you can do one thing set framework 1.0 and reinstall 1.0 packages.